# Unexplainable performance degredation with Entity Framework when generated sql command seems fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC4 application with Entity Framework for the data access.  My application has seemed to perform pretty well until thus far, when one of the pages is returning about 13,000+ rows, and the connection is timing out.  Plus, after I try to run the page that returns the 13,000+ rows, the rest of the site starts going really slow as well. Although I am using a fairly complicated linq query, I'm using the Stack Exchange miniprofiler, and using the sql from this, I've determined my query is taking less than a second (verified by running the generated sql from the LINQ query in SSMS directly; maybe 2 seconds, top).  The profiler will say something like "T+0.97ms, Reader 10393ms" for even a small returned result set.  It will get back to normal eventually.

I've looked around with little success for documentation on what the READER statement is telling me.  Does this mean that the is the time it takes to stream the results back to the web server?  Anyways, if anybody has any idea what could be going on here I'd appreciate it greatly.  I can post the LINQ code if anyone wants it, but like I said, I'm pretty confident the SQL it's generating is good.

Thanks

Edit:  One thing I might mention:  this is in a shared hosting environment running under medium trust.  Also, here is the timeout stack trace if relevant:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\sam\Desktop\MiniProfiler\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 175 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommand

Comment: If it is shared hosting environment it can be simply some performance threshold your hosting provider is using. It is hard to say what can be a real issue because we don't see your code, we don't know how you manage context lifetime, etc.

Comment: It seems to me that the command itself was wrong from the prospective of the entity framework or rather the underlying provider (SqlClient) This is why it broke when it tried to run the command. Perhaps you could try to run the command from the entity framework by doing context.ExecuteStoreCommand and passing in the generated sql to confirm. if it runs successfuly, it means that the underlying provider (SqlClient) maybe doesn't like your linq query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out.  Unfortunately, I wasn't really allowed to post the code, but it turns out that adding .AsNoTracking() to the end of my Linq query got the reader execution time down to about 3-4 seconds.  I'm guessing that materializing so many objects with change tracking enabled to such a large model was the bottleneck.  This is acceptable as this is a read-only listing.

@bleepzter, I tried your suggestion and running the Sql directly was much faster, so this definitely led me on the path to the solution.